# react class component: how to wait until some code is finished and then render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code that requests data from backend DB and load the results into a table on the web page.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from 'mui-datatables';
import {tableColumns} from './TableColumns';
import api from '../utils/api';


class ReceivedHistoryTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      columns: tableColumns,
      data: []
    };

    this.getTableData();
  }

  getTableData() {
    api.get('/project', {}).then(
      data => {
        const {issues, users} = data.project
        
        this.state.data = issues.map(function(issue){
          
          const u = users.find(user => user.id === issue.userIds[0])

          return [
            issue.title,
            issue.deadline,
            issue.status,
            issue.createdAt,
            (u && u.name) ? (u.name) : ('Not Assigned')
          ]
        })

        console.log('check 1: ', this.state.data)

      },
      
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }

  
  render() {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    const options = {
      print: false,
      download: false,
      selectableRowsHideCheckboxes: true,
      selectableRows: 'None',
      filterType: "textField",
      responsive: 'stacked',
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      page: 1
    };

    console.log("check 2", this.state.data)

    return (
      <MUIDataTable
        title="My Table"
        data={this.state.data}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ReceivedHistoryTable;
```

The problem is that even though there is valid data in the backend DB, as I can confirm by checking the console log `console.log('check 1: ', this.state.data)`, the table component says that no data was available.

This was because when it renders and returns the `MUIDataTable` component, `this.state.data` is not loaded with data yet.

`console.log("check 2", this.state.data)` executes before `console.log('check 1: ', this.state.data)`

I'm struggling with 2 questions:

1. How can I make sure that my component renders after `this.getTableData();` finishes?
2. Why my component does not re-render when after 0.1 second, `this.state.data` is updated with fetched data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this.setState()` to let React know the state has changed.

```
  getTableData() {
    api.get('/project', {}).then(
      data => {
        const {issues, users} = data.project
        
        this.setState({data: issues.map(function(issue){
          
          const u = users.find(user => user.id === issue.userIds[0])

          return [
            issue.title,
            issue.deadline,
            issue.status,
            issue.createdAt,
            (u && u.name) ? (u.name) : ('Not Assigned')
          ]
        }));

        console.log('check 1: ', this.state.data)

      },
      
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

You shouldn't be modifying `this.state` directly. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check to see if data is loaded and only then render the table like using a state variable or just checking if data array is empty. And always use `this.setState` for updating the state of a component. It does the work of informing React that an update is required.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setState, something like this (only when you get all the data the 'loading...' will change to your page):

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.getData();
}

getData = async() => {
    // get data from api
    this.setState({data: ...}, () => {
        // do something after the setState finished get data
        loader: false
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        {this.state.loader ? <>loading...</> : <div>your page</div>}
    );
}
```